# Sort and rearrange (distinct) arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have two `int[]` arrays `I` and `J` as follows:

```
int[] I = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 3 };
int[] J = { 8, 7, 6, 3, 2 };
```

I want to sort `I`, and then rearrange `J` using the same indices so the two arrays stay in registration. The result should be:

```
I = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
J = { 8, 7, 2, 6, 3 };
```

Comment: You want to sort `I` and then rearrange `J` using the same indexes result of the sorted `I`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In Matlab you would do it like this: [sortedA idx] = sort(A);
B(idx)

Comment: Simple answer: Define a class that has two integers.  One will be the value from `I`, and the other can be either the corresponding value from `J`, or it can be the index itself (0, 1, ... 4).  Either will work.  Define a comparator for the class that simply compares the values from `I`.  Then sort using that comparator, and the values from `J`, or the indexes, will stay together with the values from `I`.  That's how you could do it using Java's built-in `sort` (as opposed to Elliott's answer that requires that you write your own sort algorithm).

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ajb has noted in the comments above, the easiest way to implement this is to use a class modelling a tuple.

This has the advantage that you can use the `Arrays.sort` builtin which saves you from writing your own sorting  algorithm. On the other hand, there is the additional overhead of transferring data from the Tuples to the raw arrays.

However, you may find that in your application you are able to directly use the Tuple objects without transferring them back to arrays.

```
import java.util.*;

class Tuple implements Comparable<Tuple>
{
    int x;
    int y;
    Tuple(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }

    public int compareTo(Tuple another)
    {
        return Integer.compare(x, another.x);
    }
}

class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a[] = {1, 2, 4, 5, 3};
        int b[] = {8, 7, 6, 3, 2};
        Tuple arr[] = new Tuple[a.length];
        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            arr[i] = new Tuple(a[i], b[i]);
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            a[i] = arr[i].x;
            b[i] = arr[i].y;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[8, 7, 2, 6, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

I would start by writing a routine to `swap` elements in an `int[]`. Something like,

```
public static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
    if (i == j) {
        return;
    }
    int t = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = t;
}
```

Then you could use it and [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int[]%29) and something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] I = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 3 };
    int[] J = { 8, 7, 6, 3, 2 };
    for (int i = 0; i < I.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < I.length; j++) {
            if (I[i] > I[j]) {
                swap(I, i, j);
                swap(J, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("I = %s%n", Arrays.toString(I));
    System.out.printf("J = %s%n", Arrays.toString(J));
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
I = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
J = [8, 7, 2, 6, 3]
```

Comment: @RishavKundu Optimization left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be accomplished with Java 8 `IntStream` and additional `Pair` class representing a 2-tuple (I know, it's a bit ugly because we have to copy the values back to the array):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int[] I = {1, 2, 4, 5, 3};
        final int[] J = {8, 7, 6, 3, 2};

        List<Pair> pairs = IntStream.range(0, I.length)
                .mapToObj(n -> new Pair(I[n], J[n]))
                .sorted((p1, p2) -> p1.i - p2.i)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (int k=0; k < pairs.size(); k++) {
            Pair p = pairs.get(k);
            I[k] = p.i;
            J[k] = p.j;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(I));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(J));
    }

    public static class Pair {
        public int i,j;

        public Pair(int i, int j) {
            this.i = i;
            this.j = j;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[8, 7, 2, 6, 3]
```

Keeping the arrays in sync isn't very pretty, I would strongly suggest to model this properly by using an array of tuple objects instead. Then, it's much simpler:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Pair[] P = {new Pair(1,8), new Pair(2,7), new Pair(4,6),
                          new Pair(5,3), new Pair(3,2)};

        Arrays.sort(P, (p1, p2) -> p1.i - p2.i);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(P));
    }

    public static class Pair {
        public int i,j;

        public Pair(int i, int j) {
            this.i = i;
            this.j = j;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("(%d, %d)", i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[(1, 8), (2, 7), (3, 2), (4, 6), (5, 3)]
```